# how to combine the error message from jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

how to combine the error message from jquery validation. for example:

```
messages: {
    first_name: { required: "Please enter your first name." },
    email: {
         required: "Please enter a valid email address.",
         remote: "Email has been registered."
    },
    username: {
         required: "Please enter username.",
         remote: "Username has been registered."
    }
 },
```

Desired message will be like this:

> Please enter your first name, a valid email address and username

or

> Please enter your first name and username, email has been registered
>   etc.

Comment: Not understanding why you'd tag a JavaScript question with [tag:php].  Edited.

Comment: Your request is impossible using this plugin.  The best you can do is a single message for all rules on a particular field.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a "practical answerable" question.  It's asking how to do something that the plugin was never designed to do.

Comment: Again, please do not tag your question with PHP when the content has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I asked about the obstacles that I experienced when using the plugin. sorry if it's off topic. because I do not know the limits that can be done plugin.

Comment: No need to apologize.  It's just my opinion and four others would have to agree with me before the question is closed.  However, I'm very familiar with this plugin and do not believe there is any practical way this can be achieved.

Comment: roughly what no other alternative in this case?

Comment: This is simply not a feature of the plugin... if you have some idea about how to achieve this, please share.

Comment: If a field is blank, it tells you it's required... then you fill it out and maybe it's not a valid email.  In other words, this plugin evaluates each rule one at a time.  It does not spit out all the messages for one field all at once, because all rules for one field are not broken all at the same time.  And that's not even to the point where you can start to figure out how to construct a grammatically correct sentence out of everything.  Like I said, it's not possible because it's not a function of this plugin to evaluate all of the rules simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following way

You have to use `errorPlacement` for this, and the message should be the same on both, for example:

```
messages: {
first_name: { required: "Please enter your first name , valid email address and enter username ." },
email: {
     required: "Please enter your first name , valid email address and enter username .",
     remote: "Email has been registered."
},
username: {
     required: "Please enter your first name , valid email address and enter username .",
     remote: "Username has been registered."
 }
}
```

Then, assuming they have the same IDs here, your errorPlacement option would look like this:

```
errorPlacement: {
 var n = element.attr("name");
 if (n == "first_name" || n == "email" || n == "username")
error.insertAfter("#username");
else
  error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Hope this can help you